# Extracting least significant bits - why is the % operator relevant?

Tags: python-3.x, steganography

I need help to understand the below code which I found in a tutorial explaining about Steganography and LSB. However, I couldn't understand why the code writer used the modulo operator (`%`).For example, to insert the new data in the red pixels, he used `% 2`, for green `% 5` and so on. The snippet for the code is below:

```
for i, x in enumerate(data): 
        if counter < len(message_bit):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                r= int(str("{0:b}".format(x[0]))[:-1] + message_bit[counter], 2) # red
                x = (r, x[1], x[2])
                counter += 1

            elif i % 5 == 0:
                g = int(str("{0:b}".format(x[1]))[:-1] + message_bit[counter], 2) # green
                x = (x[0], g, x[2])
                counter += 1

            elif i % 11 == 0:
                pass

            else:
                b = int(str("{0:b}".format(x[2]))[:-1] + message_bit[counter], 2) #blue
                x = (x[0], x[1], b)
                counter += 1

        new_data.append(x)
```

Comment: Looks to me like the original code isn't splitting exactly on bit lines. Could be by intent, could be a bug. Fortunately, don't need to answer the question of how they chose their constants to answer why the relevant operator is used.

Comment: [Link](http://tkmr.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/07/28/223854) to the whole code for context.

Answer (score 0):

The modulo operator is used for calculating the remainder of integer division. For example, for incrementing `i`, `i % 3` would give you the cyclic results 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, etc. A conventional way would be to use this cyclic relationship to embed a bit in a different color plane.

```
if i % 3 == 0:
    # embed in the red
elif i % 3 == 1:
    # embed in the greed
else:
    # embed in the blue
```

While this code's author achieves the same decision, the results show no clear pattern and the embedding is not uniform across all color planes.

```
i = 0
    i % 2 == 0 is true  -> embed in RED
i = 1
    i % 2 == 0 is false
    i % 5 == 0 is false
    i % 11 == 0 is false
    else                 -> embed in BLUE
i = 2
    same as i = 0        -> embed in RED
i = 3
    same as i = 1        -> embed in BLUE
i = 4
    same as i = 0        -> embed in RED
i = 5
    i % 2 == 0 is false
    i % 5 == 0 is true   -> embed in GREEN

continuing with this logic....

i = 6                    -> embed in RED
i = 7                    -> embed in BLUE
i = 8                    -> embed in RED
i = 9                    -> embed in BLUE
i = 10                   -> embed in RED
i = 11                   -> SKIP

and so on and so forth
```

Since every other `i` is even, you'll embed half of your bits in red. Since `i % 5 == 0` and `i % 11 == 0` are rarely true, you'll embed the majority of the rest of your bits in blue. And only approximately 1/10th of them will go into green (specifically when `i` is 5, 15, 25, ...).

I don't know where you found this code, but in the only place I could find it, there was no explanation by the poster. So one can only guess about the choice of this weird pattern. However, based on the quality of the rest of the code, I find it likely that the author misunderstood what he should be doing, which resulted in that weird pattern. The fact that both the embedding and extraction routines follow the logic means the program works and the author didn't think past that.

Answer (score 0):

**Extracting least significant bits - why is the % operator relevant?**

well, if you choose a number that is 2^n you will return the n least significant bits, typically this is done with `bitwise and` and a mask eg...

`m % 4` or `(m % 2**2)` will return the least significant 2 bits; in the range if 0-3 inclusively.

this is the same as something like `m & 3`... ie `m & (2**n)-1`

Comment: While you do answer the bolded question and the modulo operator can indeed be used like that, it's a somewhat misleading question from the OP since he didn't understand the code. Here, the operator isn't used directly for embedding/extracting, but as a good ol' branch for which color plane to do the embedding.